# Fill column value conditionally on two different columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I searched but couldn't find this, please point me towards an answer if its already been asked.

I have three columns.  Patient names, whether they got antibiotics, and what brand of antibiotic.  Sometimes however I have a missing value from "Antibiotics" but I have notes in the third column that tell me they DIDN'T get antibiotics because the brand they received doesn't count.

```
df<-data.frame(Names=c("Patient1","patient2","Patient3","Patient4","patient5"),Antibiotics=c("Y","N","Y","","Y"), TypeAntibiotic=c("","","BrandA",,"BrandA",""))
```

I want to conditionally fill the blanks in "Antibiotics" if the third column has "BrandA".  HOWEVER I don't want to do that if there is already something in "Antibiotics"

I know that:

```
    df%>%mutate(Antibiotics=ifelse(grepl("BrandA",TypeAntibiotic),"N",Antibiotics))
```

Would give me an "N" in the column I want, but I believe it would override any "Y"'s I already had there.   How do I only put an "N" there if there's not already something in that row?

Comment: Just add another condition to the `if` part of your `ifelse()` that looks for emptiness or whatever else you're worried about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$Antibiotics[df$Antibiotics=="" & df$TypeAntibiotic=="BrandA"]<-"N"
```

Oh, I see @Antonis gave the same solution...

Answer (score 3):

here is a base R solution

```
myindex=df$Antibiotics==""&df$TypeAntibiotic=="BrandA"
df$Antibiotics[myindex]="N"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be what you are looking for,

```
df<-data.frame(Names=c("Patient1","patient2","Patient3","Patient4","patient5"),Antibiotics=c("Y","N","Y","","Y"), TypeAntibiotic=c("","","BrandA","BrandA",""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$Antibiotics <- ifelse((df$Antibiotics == "") & (df$TypeAntibiotic == "BrandA"),
                         "N", df$Antibiotics
```

Note that I slightly modified the definition of df so that the varibles are not factors.

If you want to use the code you have already, you just need

```
df%>%mutate(Antibiotics=ifelse(grepl("BrandA",TypeAntibiotic) & df$Antibiotics == "","N",Antibiotics))
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
df<-as.data.table(df)
df[Antibiotics=="" & TypeAntibiotic=="BrandA",Antibiotics:='N']
```